# How to run a text file as an executable without changing filetype

Tags: vbscript

I was wondering if I could save an executable (windows) as a text file and then run it without changing its filetype extension.
I have researched a bit but haven't found anything specific.
I would like to run a vb script that "launches" the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let someone else (in this case, `cmd`) launch the txt file.

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cmd /c mytxtfile.txt", 1, false
```

But you can use `cmd`, `runas`, `psexec`, ... but you can not directly use vbscript to start a `.txt` file as a process unless `.txt` files are not a registered file type in windows.

Comment: I'm sorry, but is there a way of just using a simple script that windows can already understand without modifying or installing anything else? I am trying this on a school computer... you know, no CMD or administrator priviledges.

Comment: @daniboy123, The posted code does not use anything that is not in windows. If, from command line, you invoke the exe/txt renamed file, it will run. The `.vbs` code in the answer just do the same, call `cmd.exe` to execute the file

Comment: how do you use the "runas" argument in a vbscript? @MC ND

Answer (score 0):

CMD.exe passes any file it doesn't know to CreateProcess.  CreateProcess looks in the file to see what to do with it, it doesn't use extensions. Therefore unknown file types can be executed by typing the full filename in a command prompt. If the filetype is registered then then cmd will do that rather than pass to CreateProcess.

Comment: Can you do it without CMD involved?

Comment: No. Only CMD and Explorer start files, and explorer doesn't pass unknown files to CreateProcess (the API call that actually starts programs).

Comment: `cmd /c programname.exe` starts cmd and exits after program is started.